# Using Nginx as a HTTPS reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to setup an Nginx server to reverse proxy a tomcat web service (which I don't have access to). This is essentially because the Tomcat server is running TLSv1.0 so I'm trying to bump up the version.

However, when I try to access the proxy I'm getting a 502 error. The Ngnix logs are showing - `SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream`.

Here's my Nginx configuration -

```
ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/public.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/private.key;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers  AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

server {
    listen 6003;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com:6003;
    }
}
```

I've tried the same thing with Apache but see exactly the same error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar answer to [nginx as reverse proxy with upstream SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/341023/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-upstream-ssl/717926#717926). There are separate [ssl settings](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_protocols) to set the acceptable protocols for your upstream proxy

```
...

server {

    listen 6003;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/private.key;
    ... other settings

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com:6003;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.pem;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    }
}
```

The three listed values for `proxy_ssl_protocols` are the current default set but they could conceivably change in future releases to remove TLSv1 and TLSv1.1.

Comment: Thanks! I actually managed to get it working by using `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1` only. Having the other two version in there gave me the same error, but removing them solved the problem,