# NGINX fails to connect to Nextcloud instance

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have a server running proxmox with 3 VMs: NGINX, Bitwarden and Nextcloud. Bitwarden works fine which proves that NGINX is working ok, however when NGINX tries to connect to Nextcloud it will result in a 502 error. These VMs are configured with bridges and are all accessible by NGINX.

Ideally I would like NGINX to handle SSL.

I am using the Nextcloud AIO docker image, the AIO interface works fine, only traffic proxied through NGINX is resulting in a 502.

Here is the relevant section of my NGINX config:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name nextcloud.verumignis.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/verumignis.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/verumignis.com/privkey.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.2.48:443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name nextcloud.verumignis.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.2.48:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

Here is the error in the NGINX error log:

```
2023/10/02 00:18:53 [error] 2381#2381: *573 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error:SSL alert number 80) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.1.69, server: nextcloud.verumignis.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://192.168.2.48:443/", host: "nextcloud.verumignis.com", referrer: "https://192.168.2.48:8080/"
```

When ports 80 and 443 are forwarded directly to Nextcloud it works fine, but obviously that breaks the other services running.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: so, you have some server at `192.168.2.48` listening for https on port 443, with a valid SSL certificate? See, the way I used to use nginx as a proxy, letting nginx do the hard work of the SSL encryption, the proxied server (192.168.2.48) would only need http, not https, as nginx does the hard lifting for SSL ... so I would just use `proxy_pass http://192.168.2.48:80;` in `server { listen 443 ssl; ...`

Comment: 192.168.2.48 should have a valid cert because when ports 443 and 80 are pointed directly at nextcloud it works fine. When I try to point NGINX to port 80 on nextcloud it will repeatedly redirect me to the encrypted site, thus causing a redirect loop.

Is there some way to force nextcloud to not use encryption?

Comment: So, 192.168.2.48 is a self hosted nextcloud? why "should" it have a valid cert? Did you configure one on it? and the certificate is for `nextcloud.verumignis.com`? what are the certificates you've configured in nginx then, the ones in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/verumignis.com/` ...

Comment: Are yo using something like nextcloud AIO in a docker container by any chance? if so, the certificates on nginx should be for `nextcloud.verumignis.com` not `verumignis.com`

Comment: 192.168.2.48 is the nextcloud AIO instance, the reason I believe it should have a valid SSL cert is because I am able to connect to it with https when the port is directly forwarded to nextcloud. NGINX is located on a separate VM at 192.168.2.49.
Does nextcloud request a new cert each time it starts? If so that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/nextcloud/all-in-one/blob/main/reverse-proxy.md) guide should help running nextcloud AIO behind a proxy

Comment: `Does nextcloud request a new cert each time it starts?` no - I think you may have the wrong certs in nginx for a start, and there's a particular way to configure nc-aio the way you want, as in the link in my previous comment

Comment: The cert is valid for nextcloud.verumignis.com, as well as the other services running on my network.

Comment: nut nextcloud AIO gets its own cert, that's one of the things AIO does is it not?

Comment: The link you sent appears to be when nextcloud is running on the same server as NGINX, in my case they are on separate VMs.
I think a possible solution may be to allow nextcloud to run on port 80 then handle SSL at NGINX, however I cant find much online on how to do this.

Comment: Isn't there a port 8080 that "always works" (that's something I read in the documentation anyway) so `proxy_pass http://192.168.2.48:8080;` for the `listen 443 ssl;` server?

Comment: Port 8080 works ok, it is the AIO config, I believe it uses a self signed cert as I get a warning when connecting. After I click the "take me to nextcloud" button in the AIO interface it will give me a 502 as it goes back to using port 443.

Comment: is that an NGINX warning? since 8080 uses a self signed cert, it'd be `https://192.168.2.48:8080` for the `proxy_pass` I guess ... and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/341023/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-upstream-ssl) could help too ... edit: oh, wait, so that's not for regular traffic then

Comment: 8080 goes directly to nextcloud, it is not routed through NGINX. The warn is from firefox telling me it is self signed.

Comment: well, I didn't say to do that! I misunderstood what port 8080 was for though

Comment: Ill try `proxy_ssl_verify off;` when I next get a chance, I believe that may be the solution. Thanks for the help:)

Comment: why do you have 2 root location for the same server configured? moreover, nginx does not validate by default the proxy certificate