# Nginx reverse proxying to HTTPS upstream getting 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

My goal is to write Jasmine (a JavaScript BDD testing framework) tests that exercise a back-end API built by a separate team.

I have a Jasmine server running on port 9000.  That code issues AJAX requests with a relative path that begin with /web/.  I want those requests to be directed to the backend.

So far, I've got a reverse proxy to an upstream block like so:

```
upstream backend {
  server api-dev.example.com;
}

server {
  ...

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    ...
  }

  location /web/ {
    proxy_pass https://backend/web/;
    ...
  }
}
```

Traffic to '/' is working fine, but the AJAX requests (for example, to

```
http://localhost:50000/web/internal?action=network-statistics
```

) are 502'ing.  I believe it's hitting the correct endpoint but there's an SSL error.  Nginx's error log seem to confirm my suspicion:

```
2013/12/13 16:55:28 [error] 1885#0: *257 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /web/internal/stats?action=network-statistics&request=null HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://50.18.192.173:80/web/internal/stats?action=network-statistics", host: "localhost:50000", referrer: "http://localhost:50000/"
```

However, if I change the upstream block to:

```
upstream backend {
  server api-dev.example.com:443;
}
```

…then I get 404s.  Coulda sworn I'd seen similar configurations work elsewhere on Server Fault.  For example, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/298971/can-nginx-listen-on-port-80-but-send-upstream-to-backend-using-ssl-on-443?lq=1) is a very similar question.  What am I missing?  What could be going wrong?  Sorry if this is vague, I'm happy to add more detail.

Comment: What goals you are trying to achieve? When you have 502s what url are you accessing? You need to be more specific to let anyone to help you.

Comment: Thanks number5, I've updated the above with more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove /web/. I think you're getting 404 because it tried to accesss /web/web which is not exist. You should be able to find more hint from Nginx logs.

```
upstream backend {
        server api-dev.example.com:443;
}

server {
        ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        ...
    }

    location /web/ {
        proxy_pass https://backend;
        ...
    }
}
```